# Jquery script with AJAX, doesn't work all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Jquery script that calculates the number of days between two dates and changes the color of the cell according to the time left.

Now, the calculation works but what it doesn't work all the times is that when I open the tab where this information is displayed most of the times the first time I open it, it works but then if I click on it again or if I click on another tab, it won't display the change of color.

```
<script>
      function expiryDates() {
        var warning = "<?php echo config('WARNING_DATE')?>";
        var critical = "<?php echo config('CRITICAL_DATE')?>";
        //gets and creates array of all TD 'lod' dates
        var expDate = "<?php echo $content['lod'] ?>";
        //var value = $(this).text();
        expDate = expDate.split("-");
        //Gets today's date and formats it to MYSQL date format
        var now = (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        now = now.split("-");
        //Converts all TD dates into days
        var eDate = new Date(expDate[0] + "-" + expDate[1] + "-" + expDate[2]);
        //Converts today's date into day
        var sDate = new Date(now[0] + "-" + now[1] + "-" + now[2]);
        //Does the math
        var daysApart = Math.abs(Math.round((sDate - eDate) / 86400000));
        //Changes cells color
        if (daysApart < critical) {
        //$("#expiration-date").addClass('expired');
        $("#expiration-date").css("color", "red");
        } else if ((daysApart > critical) && (daysApart <= warning)) {
        $("#expiration-date").css("color", "#orange");
        // $("#expiration-date").addClass('about_expired');
        } else if (eDate < sDate) {
        $("#expiration-date").css("color", "red");
        // $("#expiration-date").addClass('expired');
        }
        }
  </script>
```

I have used as well:

```
$( document ).ready( expiryDates);
```

and

```
$( window ).on( "load", expiryDates);
```

but the result is the same.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit:

Sorry for the missing information.

The way this is setup, is that I have a main blade that calls this information tab:

The main blade has this code:

```
<td class="detail-slide-specifications" id="detail-slide-specifications{{ $item['mainHwID'] }}" onclick="showSpecifications({{ $item['mainHwID'] }})">
```

and this is the AJAX call:

```
function showSpecifications(masterID)
{
    var itemID = "#detail-panel-specs" + masterID ;
    var loadingImgClass = ".specifications_loading_spinner_" + masterID ;

    if (masterID == "") {
        $(itemID).html( "Error : No Master ID");
        return;
    } else {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "get_specifications?masterID=" + masterID,
            type: "get",
            timeout: 5000
        });
        request.done(function (responseText) {
            $(loadingImgClass).hide();
            $(itemID).html(responseText);
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $(loadingImgClass).hide();
            $(itemID).html("Error " + errorThrown);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Ajax code that calls the function

Comment: What about async property of the ajax call?

Comment: Try to make a fiddle that reproduce your issue.

Comment: There is no ajax call here.  No idea if your page has an element with id='expiration-date'.  I don't know what values are getting filled in by PHP, perhaps you could view source on the page when it's not working and see what var warning, critical, and expDate contain.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information. I just added it to my post.

Comment: The thing, is that sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, that's what I am failing to understand. Unfortunately I cannot give a fiddle due to the complexity of this

Comment: Maybe you need to run `expiryDates()` after your ajax stuff loads, so after the last line in your request.done callback func.

Comment: I tried this:

var request = $.ajax({
            url: "get_specifications?masterID=" + masterID,
            type: "get",
            success: expiryDates,
        });

and this too:

       request.done(function (responseText) {
            $(loadingImgClass).hide();
            $(itemID).html(responseText);
            callback(expiryDates);

        });

But now the color don't change at all. 

AM I doing something wrong?